# How to get the url of currently playing video in UIWebview

Tags: ios, uiwebview, youtube, uiwebviewdelegate

Is there any way to get the link of currently playing video.I am loading ***m.youtube.com*** .For some videos it is not even entering the delegates.I tried using a NStimer as well.But for some videos it is not the clicked url

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a hacky way of doing it by listening for the `AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification` notification. This notification is fired when a UIWebView shows the media player, and it sends an `AVPlayerItem` as the notification's object.

For example:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(playerItemBecameCurrent:)
                                             name:@"AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification"
                                           object:nil];


-(void)playerItemBecameCurrent:(NSNotification*)notification {
    AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [notification object];
    if(playerItem == nil) return;
    // Break down the AVPlayerItem to get to the path
    AVURLAsset *asset = (AVURLAsset*)[playerItem asset];
    NSURL *url = [asset URL];
    NSString *path = [url absoluteString];
}
```

This works for any video (and audio). However, I noticed you mentioned YouTube - it's worth pointing out Apple **WILL** reject your app if it has the ability to download YouTube videos **AT ALL**, because it's against [YouTube's Terms of Service](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms).

Comment: Thank you ,Its working.Still I am not able to get the current url corresponding to the video.Is there any way ?

Comment: @Jeff What do you mean? My example code above shows getting the URL as a NSURL and NSString. This is the URL of the video that is being played.

Comment: I am getting encoded url.I am asking about the youtube link of the vide

Comment: When you click on a video page, `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` is called just like every other web page. The request contains the URL, which will be something like `http://m.youtube.com/?#/watch?v=(videoid)`

Comment: for some videos it's not entering in this delegate.that is my problem

Comment: @Jeff Can you give any more information about that? I tested it just then and every video page that I tested called `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:`

Comment: Sorry dude, I am not able to give the URL because of the privacy of the app.I am sorry for that.For some videos it is not entering.I think if you click several links, you can reproduce he same

Comment: any solution for the dilemma ?

Comment: @ev0lution I am trying to just update the video volume using a similar approach you mentioned, do you think it is legit to do so? I mean, compliant with Apple and Youtube's terms?

Comment: @ev0lution, my post is here in case you'd like to post your opinion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37290108/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-uiwebview-muted/37315071#37315071

Comment: Not working now in WKWebView can you help me please .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview my question is this help me .

Answer (score 0):

This one is for swift version:

//Add NSNotificationcenter for current playing song

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(playerItemBecameCurrent), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification"), object:nil)
}
```

//Fetch path from notificationcenter

```
@objc func playerItemBecameCurrent(notification:NSNotification){
    let playerItem:AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
    let asset:AVURLAsset=playerItem.asset as! AVURLAsset
    let url = asset.url
    let path = url.absoluteString
    print(path)

}
```

Comment: Is this not work in WKWebView please any suggestion how to do that in WKWebView ?